Why is the colimit unique up to isomorphism?
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure how to prove that the colimit is unique up to isomorphism.
Let's say $M$ and $M'$ are two colimits of diagrams with $\mu_i:M_i\to M$, $\mu_{ij}:M_i\to M_j$, and $\mu_i':M_i\to M'$ the respective maps. Then by the definition of a colimit, I have (unique) homomorphisms $\alpha:M\to M'$ and $\beta:M'\to M$ satisfying that $\alpha\circ\beta\circ\mu_i' = \mu_i'$ and $\beta\circ\alpha\circ\mu_i=\mu_i$. Thus $\alpha,\beta$ are inverses on some "subset" of $M$ and $M'$, and I'm morally convinced that this is enough to show that $\alpha,\beta$ are actually inverses, but I'm just not quite sure how to state that.
I'm sure it has to do with the fact that the maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are themselves unique since otherwise its clear to me the colimit is not always unique. But what is the actual argument here? The thing I want to argue is that $\alpha\circ\beta$ is the unique endomorphism fixing $\mu_i$ (respectively $\alpha\circ\beta$ fixing $\mu_i'$) and since the identity is an endomorphism fixing $\mu_i$ (respective $\mu_i'$), then their compositions must be the identity. My problem with this argument is that it would work if $M'=M_1$, $\mu_1'={\rm id}_{M_1}$, and $\beta=\mu_1$. Then obviously $\alpha\circ\mu_i\circ{\rm id}_{M_1}={\rm id}_{M_1}$ and $\mu_i\circ\alpha\circ\mu_i=\mu_i$, but in general $M$ is not isomorphism to $M_i$, so somewhere I need to also use the hypothesis that the colimit diagram commutes for all $M_i$ but I'm not sure how to do that. I want to argue that the colimit is minimal in some sense, since otherwise the homomorphism $\alpha$ wouldn't be unique, but I'm just not exactly sure how to phrase it.
I tried to find other explanations on stack exchange or online, but nowhere seems to work out all the details of this proof to my satisfaction.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Hint: Use uniqueness on $\beta\circ\alpha \circ \mu_i = \mu_i = \mathrm{id} \circ \mu_i$.

@tzimmo This ignores my questions... I say in my post that this is exactly the argument I want to make, but it doesn't seem to actually make sense to me. Why does this not prove the colimit is isomorphic to any $M_i$ (and is hence a nonsense proof)?

In your post you add the identity on $M_i$ to the right of $\mu_i$. Instead, add the identity on $M$ to the left (which is the side $\beta \circ \alpha$ is also on).

@Vibbz $M’ = M_1$ doesn’t make any sense though. You have to have maps $\mu_i’: M_i \to M’$ for all $i$. While $\mu_1’$ can be $\text{id}_{M_1}$, what is, say, $\mu_2’$?

@DavidGao Suppose $\mu_i=0$ for all $i\neq 1$. We still have that $\alpha\circ\mu_1\circ{\rm id_{M_1}}={\rm id_{M_1}}={\rm id_{M_1}}\circ {\rm id_{M_1}}$ and $\mu_1\circ\alpha\circ\mu_1=\mu_1={\rm id_{M}}\circ \mu_1$, and thus it seems like uniqueness would guarantee that $\alpha\circ\mu_1$ and $\mu_1\circ\alpha$ are the respective identitites. This construction is no longer a colimit of the $M_i$ but thats my point of confusion, it doesnt seem like you need the object to be a colimit to construct an isomorphism with this argument.

If $\mu_i=0$ for all $i\neq 1$, then you require that for all $j$ comparable to $1$ you have $\mu_j\mu_{1j} = \mathrm{id}{M_1}$ or $\mathrm{id}{M_1}\mu_{ji}=\mu_j$. But the first equation would tell you that $\mathrm{id}_{M_1}=0$, so $M_1$ would have to be zero for all $j\geq 1$. If you have all those assumptions, then your objection just becomes the assertion that if the diagram works then the diagram works.

@Vibbz First of all, unless you’re in, say the category of vector spaces or something like that, setting $\mu_i = 0$ makes no sense. Second of all, even if the zero map makes sense, what is $\alpha$? A morphism $\alpha$ from the colimit $M$ to $M’$ exists when you have the compatibility condition $\mu_j’ \circ \mu_{ij} = \mu_i’$ whenever there is a morphism $\mu_{ij}: M_i \to M_j$ in the colimit diagram. If you just set $\mu_i’ = 0$, there is no reason for this compatibility condition to be satisfied.

@Vibbz And even if the compatibility is somehow satisfied, the proof needs $\beta \circ \alpha \circ \mu_i = \mu_i$, which is not going to happen for $i \neq 1$ in general. Indeed, when $i \neq 1$, $\alpha \circ \mu_i = \mu_i’ = 0$ by construction of $\alpha$, so $\beta \circ \alpha \circ \mu_i = \mu_i$ implies $\mu_i = 0$, which rarely happens.

By the universal property of the colimit, given any object $N$ and morphisms $\eta_i\colon M_i\to N$ such that for all suitable $i,j$ we have $\eta_j\circ\mu_{ij} = \eta_i$, there exists a unique morphism $E\colon M\to N$ such that $\eta_i = E\mu_i$. The same holds for $M'$ and the $\mu'_i$.
Now take $N=M$ and $\eta_i=\mu_i$. Clearly, $\mathrm{id}_M\colon M\to M$ satisfies that $\mu_i=\mathrm{id}_M\mu_i$ for all $i$.
But $\beta\circ\alpha$ also satisfy this condition. It is a morphism from $M$ to $M$ with the property that $(\beta\circ\alpha)\mu_i = \mu_i$ for all $i$. By the uniqueness clause of the universal property of $M$, it follows that $\beta\circ\alpha=\mathrm{id}_M$. Symmetrically, $\alpha\circ\beta=\mathrm{id}_{M'}$ by the uniqueness clause of the universal property of $M'$ as a colimit.
But that means that $\alpha\circ\beta=\mathrm{id}_{M'}$ and $\beta\circ\alpha = \mathrm{id}_M$, and that means that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are inverses of each other.  Thus, $M$ and $M'$ are isomorphic.
The isomorphism is unique relative to the structure morphisms $\mu_{i}$ and $\mu'_i$. It is not an absolute "uniquely isomorphic", it is "there is a unique isomorphism $\alpha\colon M\to M'$ such that $\mu'_i = \alpha\mu_i$ for all $i$."
You say:

My problem with this argument is that it would work if $M'=M_1$, $\mu_1'={\rm id}_{M_1}$, and $\beta=\mu_1$. Then obviously $\alpha\circ\mu_i\circ{\rm id}_{M_1}={\rm id}_{M_1}$ and $\mu_i\circ\alpha\circ\mu_i=\mu_i$, but in general $M$ is not isomorphism to $M_i$, so somewhere I need to also use the hypothesis that the colimit diagram commutes for all $M_i$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

This doesn't make much sense. Remember what the universal property of $M$ says:

If $N$ is any object, and $\{\eta_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of morphisms such that $\eta_i\colon M_i\to N$ for every $i\in I$ are such that if $r,s\in I$ with $r\leq s$, $\eta_s\circ\mu_{rs} = \mu_r$, then there exists a unqiue morphism $E\colon M\to N$ such that $\eta_s = E\circ\mu_s$ for every $s\in I$.

You take $N=M_1$. Fine. You take $\eta_1\colon M_1\to N$ to be the identity map. Fine. But that is all you do. There is no universal property to be applied here to get a morphism $M\to M_1$, because we do not have a family of morphisms from every $M_s$ to $M_1$. Until you define such a family, there is no guarantee of a map from $M$ to $N$, nor if there is a map is there a guarantee of uniqueness.  You do not know if there is map from $M$ to $M_1$, and the universal property of $M$ does not give you any such morphism unless you also have maps $\eta_j\colon M_j\to M_1$ with the required properties. And there is no "uniqueness clause" to apply because you do not have a diagram of maps, you are only looking at a single map that happens to involve $M_1$.

This essentially ignores my main question though, which is about the step "by the uniqueness clause of the universal property of $M$..." i.e. why does this argument not show that $M$ is isomorphic to $M_i$ as per my original question?

@Vibbz: The universal map $E$ must satisfy that $E\eta_i=\mu_i$ for all $i$. And the maps $\eta_j$ must satisfy that whenever $i\leq j$, $\eta_j\mu_{ij}=\eta_i$. If you posit that $M=M_1$ and $\mu'1=\mathrm{id}$, then you also need that for all $j$ with $1\leq j$ you have $\mu_j\mu{ij} = \mathrm{id}{M_1}$, and for all $j\leq 1$ you have $\mathrm{id}{M_1}\mu_{ji} = \mu_j$. If that were true, the conclusion is not "$M$ is isomorphic to $M_i$", the conclusion is "$M$ is isomorphic to $M_1$"... which is what you are assuming to begin with.

@ArturoMagidin No I'm saying let $M'=M_1$. This is no longer a colimit of the $M_i$ because I haven't defined any other maps. I didn't assume $M=M_1$ I'm assuming $M'=M_1$ (or equivalently, assuming any $M'=M_i$ for any $i$) and then using the uniqueness argument (probably incorrectly, but this is my confusion) to obtain that $M\cong M' = M_1$.

@Vibbz You are assuming that $M$ and $M'$ are both colimits. If you aren't assuming that, then what is the point of the question? You cannot apply the universal property unless you have a family of maps from every $M_j$ to $M'$ that satisfy the relevant equation. You can't just define it for a single $M_1$ and then try to invoke the universal property; it doesn't work like that.

@ArturoMagidin I'm assuming that $M$ is a colimit and $M'$ is not. So I do have the universal property for $\alpha$. Unless I'm horribly confused, $M_1$ with ${\rm id}_{M_1}$ should satisfy the same universal property specifically for $M_1$, i.e. I guess it is a colimit of just $M_1$ by itself. Then I don't understand why I can't apply uniqueness to $\alpha$ and $\beta=\mu_1$ (in this case) and obtain that $\alpha,\beta$ are inverses of each other. What is missing?

@Vibbz You don't have the universal property unless you have maps from every $M_j$ to $M'$ that make a commutative diagram.
